Identifying and Redirecting Duplicate Column Values in SSIS 2019
To be clear this is not a requirement to identify and redirect or dedupe rows in the data flow task leveraging the Sort Transformation. Instead, the requirement is to identify the duplicate values in a column then handle affected rows differently. Using the attached mock-up table, ProductID 1002 will quality as duplicates, therefore rows 3 and 4 should flow down a different path. Likewise, ProductCode A01 resulting in rows 2 and 6 being redirected.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!
Mock-up Table
I tried splitting the dataset then performing joins but that didn't work as intended.

If this is a large dataset, the sorts will cause performance issues.  However, if you must do this in SSIS instead of the database, this is what it could look like:


Get your source data, whatever that is.  Some sources will allow you to specify a source column that it is sorted by, but we'll assume we have no control over that.
Sort by ProductID
Add a multicast to rejoin the raw rows by product ID later
Aggregate by ProductID and select (*) as Count All
Add a conditional split with 1 condition: (DT_I4)[Count all] > 1
Add two more sorts by ProductID for each path
Use a merge join to bring the original rows back again.  See image below for configuration example:



Mark Wojciechowicz, thank you for your proposed engineering approach. I've spent the last few days performance testing, and you're right, attempts to sort large datasets in the data flow aren't ideal. I'm exploring other approaches to solve my use case. However, I accepted your solution as the answer because it set me on the right path, and I believe it will be helpful to others.
Thank you!
